# Understanding the lazy function in Swift 2

Tags: swift

I came across [this article](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/07/26/lazy-by-name-lazy-by-nature/) that explains the concepts of `lazy` collections and sequences and had the following sample code:

```
var i = 0
let lf = lazy(1...5).filter { _ in
    ++i % 2 == 0
}
let a1 = lf.array // a1 is [2, 4]
let a2 = lf.array // a2 is [1, 3, 5]
let a3 = lf.array
// a3 is [2, 4]
```

In Swift 2, this doesn't quiet work. I thought the updated version would look more like this:

```
var ix = 0
let lf = (1...5).lazy.filter { _ in
    ++ix % 2 == 0
}

let a1 = lf.array
```

But using lf.array produces the error:

```
'array' is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...)
```

What does this error exactly mean? How do I achieve the Swift 2 equivalent of this code?

Comment: `let a1 = Array(lf)` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about...

```
var ix = 0
let lf = LazyCollection(1...5).filter {  _ in
    ++ix % 2 == 0
    }
let a1 = lf
print(a1.count,a1.first!,ix) // yields: 2 2 8
```

Note: **ix is 8**.  Is this what you'd want?